# Setting state_selected in nav drawer

Tags: android

Hey I'm trying to add a selected state to my Nav Drawer. Everything is pretty boilerplate from the implementation here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

There's some custom style in there and I'm trying to style a custom selected state for the List View (the list view that is actually the nav drawer)

I created a selector for the list items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@color/darkerGrey" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/mediumGrey" android:state_selected="true"/>
</selector>
```

and I'm seeing the style work for the "pressed" state, but I'm not seeing the "selected" state work. In code to make it selected I'm using the ListView method setItemChecked:

```
mDrawerList.setItemChecked(0, true);
```

I've also set on my ListView the property

```
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice! Thanks!

p.s. I've tried using "state_checked" as well, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

try setting this selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@color/darkerGrey" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/mediumGrey" android:state_selected="true"/>
</selector>
```

to the `listView` as:

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/your_selector"
```

or

to the `list_row_layout` that you use for inflating into the list as:

```
android:background="@drawable/your_selector"
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the help, the first solution you suggestion was and is already in place when I posted this question, I tried the other suggestion and I still am not getting an active state, just the pressed state. Thanks for the help!

Comment: for the active state, add android:state_activated="true" and its drawable.